# Swift: Container View layout changes when rotating and rotating back again

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-autolayout

I am working in Xcode 7, using Autolayout and targeting iOS 9.3. I have a Main View Controller that holds a Container View. The Container View holds a Child View Controller.

The Container View has a leading and trailing constraint of -20 so that it covers the Main View Controller fully in the horizontal.

When the Main View Controller loads for the first time, however, the content from the Child View Controller that is displayed inside the Container is slightly cut off on the left and the right (almost as if it does not recognize the constraint of -20 on the left and the right).

When I rotate the device to landscape and then back again to the original portrait orientation the Child View Controller suddenly scales correctly and is no longer cut off on the left and the right.

So it looks like some layout method is being called when rotating the device sideways and rotating it back again that does not get called when the view is first loaded. What method could this be? Is there a way that I can manually call this method to force an update on the layout/size when the child is first loaded so that it looks the same as after a rotation and backwards rotation?

Comment: please show codez. From my experience with autolayout, you should always suspect your code to be the culprit in such situations, so what most probably happens is that your constraints setup is not what you think it is, but cannot say more without seeing the code.

Comment: You can call `layoutIfNeeded()` on a view to trigger an update to the layout. As regards the method you're looking for: assuming you're not using rotation methods, the method triggered by a change in orientation will be `viewWillTransitionToSize:`

Comment: I have tried calling layoutIfNeeded() inside the Container View's viewDidAppear method. I have also tried calling it in the Child View Controller's viewDidAppear method but this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to set the margin for -20. The 0 margin every side of container view is fairly enough to make the child view to spread out of the main container view. I have tried your idea but there is no problem. You can download the project from the github link below;

[The link](https://github.com/yilmazalican/Deneme)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem:

Instead of setting a leading and a trailing constraint of -20 on the Container View, I set a constraint on the Container View for the same width as the Main View and to center it horizontally in the container.

With these constraints it works on first load although I cannot quite explain why this would behave differently to the original constraints. I guess the lesson is that with Autolayout if one way of sizing your container behaves awkwardly under certain circumstances, try another set of constraints to achieve the same result.

Comment: stanley,i have an issue with container while using the app.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008852/uipageviewcontroller-within-a-containerview-is-not-working-properly) . this is the link.please just have give a look.